# Голосовой ассистент не реагирует на команды, но нет ошибки

Tags: python

Сделал своего голосового ассистента, все работало исправно до перехода на Windows(Я сидел на Linux). При произнесении имени ассистента он показывает что услышал User said: имя, но на команду никак не реагирует, ошибки так же нет.
Вот сам код:

```
from ast import While
import json
import datetime as dt
import pyaudio
from vosk import Model, KaldiRecognizer
import pyttsx3
import os
import pygame
import time
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import platform
import webbrowser
import subprocess
import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
    QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
    QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
    QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
    QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QLineEdit, QMainWindow, QPushButton,
    QSizePolicy, QStatusBar, QWidget)

class Ui_LoginWindow(object):
    with open('commands.json', 'r') as file:
        commands_data = json.load(file)
        commands = commands_data.get('commands', [])
def setupUi(self, LoginWindow):
    if not LoginWindow.objectName():
        LoginWindow.setObjectName(u"LoginWindow")
    LoginWindow.resize(480, 157)
    LoginWindow.setMinimumSize(QSize(480, 157))
    LoginWindow.setMaximumSize(QSize(480, 157))
    icon = QIcon()
    icon.addFile(u"1679059321_bogatyr-club-p-fioletovii-fon-kiberpank-foni-vkontakte-80.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
    LoginWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
    LoginWindow.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(1, 0, 31);")
    self.centralwidget = QWidget(LoginWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
    self.LoginEnter = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.LoginEnter.setObjectName(u"LoginEnter")
    self.LoginEnter.setGeometry(QRect(290, 60, 161, 51))
    self.LoginEnter.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(56, 56, 56);")
    self.NoAccount = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.NoAccount.setObjectName(u"NoAccount")
    self.NoAccount.setGeometry(QRect(230, 0, 251, 34))
    self.NoAccount.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(56, 56, 56);")
    self.LoginLogin = QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.LoginLogin.setObjectName(u"LoginLogin")
    self.LoginLogin.setGeometry(QRect(20, 40, 221, 41))
    self.LoginLogin.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(56, 56, 56);")
    self.LoginPassword = QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.LoginPassword.setObjectName(u"LoginPassword")
    self.LoginPassword.setGeometry(QRect(20, 90, 221, 41))
    self.LoginPassword.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(56, 56, 56);")
    self.LoginPassword.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
    LoginWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.statusbar = QStatusBar(LoginWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
    LoginWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

    self.retranslateUi(LoginWindow)
    self.LoginEnter.clicked.connect(self.login)
    QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(LoginWindow)

def login(self):
    is_gosha_active = False
    last_command_time = None
    username = self.LoginLogin.text()
    password = self.LoginPassword.text()

    try:
        with open('accounts.json') as accounts_file:
            accounts = json.load(accounts_file)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Файл 'accounts.json' не найден.")
        return
    except json.JSONDecodeError:
        print("Ошибка декодирования JSON в файле 'accounts.json'.")
        return

    for account in accounts:
        if account["username"] == username and account["password"] == password:
            print("Вход выполнен!")
            user_role = account['role']
            if user_role == 'admin':
                model = Model("vosk")
                rec = KaldiRecognizer(model, 16000)
                engine = pyttsx3.init()
                p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
                voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
                engine.setProperty('voice', voices[2].id)
                user = os.getlogin()
                now = dt.datetime.now()
                stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=16000, input=True, frames_per_buffer=8000)
                stream.start_stream()
                
                with open('commands.json', 'r') as file:
                    commands_data = json.load(file)
                    commands = commands_data.get('commands', [])

                def close_current_window():
                    system = platform.system()
                    if system == "Windows":
                        os.system("taskkill /f /im explorer.exe")
                    elif system == "Linux":
                        os.system("xdotool key Alt+F4")
                    elif system == "Darwin":
                        os.system('osascript -e "tell application \\"System Events\\" to keystroke \\"w\\" using {command down}"')

                def minimize_current_window():
                    system = platform.system()
                    if system == "Windows":
                        os.system("powershell -command $wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell; $wshell.SendKeys('% ')")
                    elif system == "Linux":
                        os.system("xdotool getactivewindow windowminimize")
                    elif system == "Darwin":
                        os.system('osascript -e "tell application \\"System Events\\" to keystroke \\"m\\" using {command down}"')

                def listen():
                    while True:
                        data = stream.read(4000, exception_on_overflow=False)
                        if (rec.AcceptWaveform(data)) and (len(data) > 0):
                            answer = json.loads(rec.Result())
                            if answer['text']:
                                user_text = answer['text']
                                print("User said:", user_text)
                                yield user_text

                def find_most_similar_command(text):
                    max_similarity = -1
                    closest_command = None
                    for command_data in commands:
                        activation_phrase = command_data.get('activation_phrase', '')
                        similarity = fuzz.token_set_ratio(text.lower(), activation_phrase.lower())
                        if similarity > max_similarity:
                            max_similarity = similarity
                            closest_command = command_data

                    return closest_command, max_similarity

                def execute_command(command):
                    global is_gosha_active, Speak

                    closest_command, similarity = find_most_similar_command(command)

                    with open('commands.json', 'r') as file:
                        commands_data = json.load(file)
                        commands = commands_data.get('commands', [])
                    if similarity >= 80:
                        response = closest_command['response']
                        engine.say(response)
                        engine.runAndWait()
                        if closest_command.get('action') == "run_mom_code":
                            time.sleep(1)
                            subprocess.Popen(["python", "mom.py"])
                        if closest_command.get('action') == "time":
                            timeh = now.hour
                            timem = now.minute
                            engine.say(timeh)
                            engine.say('часов')
                            engine.say(timem)
                            engine.say("минут")
                            engine.runAndWait()
                        if closest_command.get('action') == "open_browser":
                            webbrowser.open("https://www.google.ru/")
                        if closest_command.get('action') == "open_youtube":
                            webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/")
                        if closest_command.get('action') == "close_window":
                            close_current_window()
                        if closest_command.get('action') == "minimize_window":
                            minimize_current_window()
                        if closest_command.get('action') == "user":
                            engine.say(user)
                            engine.runAndWait()
                    else:
                        print("Команда не распознана.")

                for text in listen():
                    current_time = now
                    with open('commands.json', 'r') as file:
                        commands_data = json.load(file)
                        commands = commands_data.get('commands', [])
                    if last_command_time and (current_time - last_command_time).seconds > 7:
                        is_gosha_active = False

                    if not is_gosha_active and commands[0]["activation_phrase"] in text.lower():
                        last_command_time = now
                        is_gosha_active = True
                        print("Активация ассистента.")
                        if commands:
                            engine.say(commands[0]["response"])
                            engine.runAndWait()
                    elif is_gosha_active:
                        last_command_time = now
                        if text.lower() == commands[4]["activation_phrase"]:
                            print("Деактивация ассистента.")
                            if len(commands) > 3:
                                engine.say(commands[4]["response"])
                                engine.runAndWait()
                            sys.exit(app.exec())
                        else:
                            execute_command(text.lower())

            elif user_role == 'tester':
                print('Не доступно для тестера')
            elif user_role == 'user':
                print('Не доступно для пользователя')

def retranslateUi(self, LoginWindow):
    LoginWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("LoginWindow", u"\u0413\u043e\u043b\u043e\u0441\u043e\u0432\u043e\u0439 \u0410\u0441\u0441\u0438\u0441\u0442\u0435\u043d\u0442 \u0413\u043e\u0448\u0430(\u0412\u0445\u043e\u0434)", None))
    self.LoginEnter.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("LoginWindow", u"\u0412\u043e\u0439\u0442\u0438", None))
    self.NoAccount.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("LoginWindow", u"\u041d\u0435\u0442 \u0430\u043a\u043a\u0430\u0443\u043d\u0442\u0430? \u0417\u0430\u0440\u0435\u0433\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0440\u0438\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0442\u044c\u0441\u044f.", None))
    self.LoginLogin.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("LoginWindow", u"\u041b\u043e\u0433\u0438\u043d", None))
    self.LoginPassword.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("LoginWindow", u"\u041f\u0430\u0440\u043e\u043b\u044c", None))

class LoginWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LoginWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_LoginWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = LoginWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: В коде ничего не изменялось, я просто поменял ОС с Linux на Винду